# Disable cart page but keep the checkout page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, cart

I'm currently looking for a better way then this question here to remove / disable the cart page in my WooCommerce installation:

[Disabling shopping basket in WooCommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135025/disabling-shopping-basket-in-woocommerce)

So I want to show a 404 instead of a redirect so that it's clear that this page doesn't exists.

> The functionality must be there because my shop can't work anymore without this.

To make all clear:

---

I've build a custom button which adds the products to the "cart" and redirect directly to the checkout page. This should be the only available process!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following that will handle cart redirection:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'skip_cart_redirect' );
function skip_cart_redirect(){
    // Redirect to checkout (when cart is not empty)
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_cart() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() ); 
        exit();
    }
    // Redirect to shop if cart is empty
    elseif ( WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_cart() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

If you want to have a 404 for cart page you can use a fake page url that will make a 404 like:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cart_redirect_404' );
function cart_redirect_404(){
    // Redirect to non existing page that will make a 404
    if ( is_cart() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/cart-page/') ); 
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: So it's not possible to do it without a redirect like showing a 404 not found right?

Comment: Nope. The minicart is not enabled and visible. I've just the button "Proceed to checkout" in any product which cleans the cart, adds just the product where the button is pressed and redirect to the checkout. So there is optically no cart. No minicart and no normal cart for the user. So for example when you visit my page and know that it's WooCommerce and enter ../cart/ you should get a 404 to make clear that this is not available in the frontend. Would be my preferred solution if possible.

Comment: @Mr.Jo I have added an addition after, that should make a 404. Not sure if that is what you want. I don't see any other ways… You can also tweak htaccess file too i suppose.

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you very much!